# for loop not working for multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, for

I have a array like this "Apple Banana Clementine Date"

I have to print like this:

```
1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Clementine
4. Date
```

**Script file:**

```
for i in "${fruits[@]}"; do
    echo "$lineno. $i "
    lineno+=1
done
```

output of myscript:

```
1.             Apple
               Banana
               Clem....
```

I don't understand why it is not printing lineno and also why it is printing long gap b/w `1.` and `Apple`. Thanks.

Comment: How did you create your array?

Comment: it's out of some commands @cuonglm

Comment: Please show us how did you create your array, I think that's your problem, not quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your array. It seems that you have created an array with only one element. Try this example:

```
array=("$(printf 'Apple\nBanana\nClementine\nDate')")

for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do
  printf '%d. %s\n' $((i+1)) "${array[$i]}"
done

j=0
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
  j=$((j+1))
  printf '%d. %s\n' "$j" "$e"
done

k=0
for e in ${array[@]}; do
  k=$((k+1))
  printf '%d. %s\n' "$k" "$e"
done
```

Then run:

```
$ ./test.sh 
1. Apple
Banana
Clementine
Date
1. Apple
Banana
Clementine
Date
1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Clementine
4. Date
```

You can see, you actually create an array contains one element. The 3rd loop print four elements because the shell had performed field splitting on string `Apple\nBanana\nClementine\nDate`, which gave you four separated words back.

If you change the array to:

```
set -f
array=( $(printf 'Apple\nBanana\nClementine\nDate') )
set +f
```

(`set -f` disables wildcard expansion, in case the characters `*?\[` appear in the output of the command) you will get the desired result, which is that the output of the command is split at whitespace:

```
$ ./test.sh 
1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Clementine
4. Date
1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Clementine
4. Date
1. Apple
2. Banana
3. Clementine
4. Date
```

A note that you must use double quotes `"${array[@]}"` when you want to iterate through all array elements, or use the c-style for loop like my first example.

Comment: `networks=$(iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID | sed -r 's/(ESSID:|")//g')`. networks is my array

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: I'm using bash. y?

Comment: @linux_inside `networks=$(iwlist …)` sets `networks` to a scalar value, which is the output of the command. If you want the output to be split, you need to make the variable an array: `networks=($(iwlist …))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ fruits=(Apple Banana Clementine Date)
[sreeraj@server ~]$ (IFS=$'\n'; echo "${fruits[*]}") | nl
     1  Apple
     2  Banana
     3  Clementine
     4  Date
[sreeraj@server ~]$
```